# Tags "building" and "construction"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

Presently, tags [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) and [construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) are both in existence.

The overwhelming use of both seems to be similar -- questions relating to edifices and how they were set up (either by someone or in a specific location) though only four questions include both tags right now. Additional uses -- that wouldn't match the alternative -- seem to include, for [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building), questions about specific buildings (e.g., like [this one here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52165/what-is-this-building-called-it-was-built-in-2002), but [this one -- essentially similar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/what-is-the-oldest-building-in-the-world-still-in-use) -- isn't tagged [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building)), and, for [construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction), questions about how/when/where specific things were built (e.g., like [this one here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17290/has-the-u-s-navy-ever-commissioned-the-building-of-a-warship-overseas) which concerns ships).

**Should something be done to modify these tags, possibly through combining the two?**

An additional question, as some of the [construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) questions relate [to](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17290/has-the-u-s-navy-ever-commissioned-the-building-of-a-warship-overseas) [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/what-kind-of-wood-was-the-standard-decking-for-aircraft-carriers-in-world-war-2) [ships](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/what-is-the-origin-of-the-english-ship-building-philosophy), is whether a specific [ship-construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ship-construction) tag ([naval-architecture](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naval-architecture)/[ship-construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ship-construction)) is more apt than [construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) which is optimal for fixed-structures (let's not go too far into naval architecture here...).

Answer (score 1):

There is much more to buildings than their design and construction. Perhaps one is interested in their ownership. Or in events that took place in them. Or when they were demolished.

Besides, not all that which is constructed is actually a building. Is the Panama Canal a building? Is the Georgian Military Road a building? Is the Golden Gate Bridge a building?

Of course, it is hard to answer this question because one does not even know whether tag [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) refers to actual buildings **or** the act of building. There is no tag description.

- If the former is the case, merging is unwarranted. In my opinion, in this case, tag [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) should be renamed [buildings](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buildings) to avoid further confusion.
- If the latter is the case, merging is obviously warranted.

Comment: That's a fair point on "building" vs "buildings". The former makes sense (though the more formal definition would a "structure" vs a "building" in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

As no other answers were created, but I'm not in complete agreement with the above. I propose:

- [buildings](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buildings)/[structures](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structures) (synonymous) for specific edifices along with a Wiki that would highlight how it is meant for specific buildings (no matter where they are);
- [construction](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) to subsume the present [building](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/building) to be the only tag that represents the "history of construction".